# Enabling on-board intel graphics while stil using dedicated graphic card

Tags: linux-mint, hardware, intel-graphics

I have Radeon RX 550 graphic card ASRock Z370 PRO4 motherboard with on-board intel graphics and linux mint 18.2 and I'm trying to get both dedicated and on-board graphics working at the same time.

I have enabled **IGPU Multi-Monitor** in BIOS.

The integrated graphics is detected by the OS but shows as *UNCLAIMED*, I do not get any signal on HDMI port and `Display` program does not detect the attached display.

`sudo lshw -C video`

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Baffin [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: cf
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:127 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:df000000-df03ffff memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:de000000-deffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

`sudo lspci -nnvvvv`

```
...
00:02.0 Display controller [0380]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3e92]
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device [1849:3e92]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 11
    Region 0: Memory at de000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Region 2: Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Region 4: I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express (v2) Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0
            ExtTag- RBE+
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Not Supported, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Not Supported
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Address: 00000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] #1b
    Capabilities: [200 v1] Address Translation Service (ATS)
        ATSCap: Invalidate Queue Depth: 00
        ATSCtl: Enable-, Smallest Translation Unit: 00
    Capabilities: [300 v1] #13
    Kernel modules: i915
...
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Baffin [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X] [1002:67ff] (rev cf) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:8a91]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 127
    Region 0: Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Region 2: Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=2M]
    Region 4: I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Region 5: Memory at df000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1+,D2+,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [58] Express (v2) Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <4us, L1 unlimited
            ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag+ PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
            MaxPayload 256 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr+ UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq+ AuxPwr- TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 8GT/s, Width x8, ASPM L1, Exit Latency L0s <64ns, L1 <1us
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x8, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Not Supported, TimeoutDis-, LTR+, OBFF Not Supported
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR+, OBFF Disabled
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 8GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -3.5dB, EqualizationComplete+, EqualizationPhase1+
             EqualizationPhase2+, EqualizationPhase3+, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 00000000fee002b8  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150 v2] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP+ BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap+ CGenEn- ChkCap+ ChkEn-
    Capabilities: [200 v1] #15
    Capabilities: [270 v1] #19
    Capabilities: [2b0 v1] Address Translation Service (ATS)
        ATSCap: Invalidate Queue Depth: 00
        ATSCtl: Enable-, Smallest Translation Unit: 00
    Capabilities: [2c0 v1] #13
    Capabilities: [2d0 v1] #1b
    Capabilities: [320 v1] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Max snoop latency: 71680ns
        Max no snoop latency: 71680ns
    Capabilities: [328 v1] Alternative Routing-ID Interpretation (ARI)
        ARICap: MFVC- ACS-, Next Function: 1
        ARICtl: MFVC- ACS-, Function Group: 0
    Capabilities: [370 v1] L1 PM Substates
        L1SubCap: PCI-PM_L1.2+ PCI-PM_L1.1+ ASPM_L1.2+ ASPM_L1.1+ L1_PM_Substates+
              PortCommonModeRestoreTime=0us PortTPowerOnTime=170us
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

Following some advice on the internet I tried to create xorg.conf but without effect

```
Section "ServerLayout"      
    Identifier     "Layout0"                                            
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "amdgpu"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "intel"
    BusID          "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
EndSection
```

`/var/log/Xorg.0.log` - loading Intel driver

```
[    16.351] 
X.Org X Server 1.19.5
Release Date: 2017-10-12
[    16.351] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    16.351] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-101-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    16.351] Current Operating System: Linux agrzes-desktop 4.13.0-39-generic #44~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 5 16:43:10 UTC 2018 x86_64
[    16.351] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-39-generic root=UUID=60626327-5d73-48cd-ba79-0f94b318e6c8 ro quiet splash radeon.audio=1 vt.handoff=7
[    16.351] Build Date: 24 November 2017  09:44:25AM
[    16.351] xorg-server 2:1.19.5-0ubuntu2~16.04.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    16.351] Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
[    16.351]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    16.351] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    16.351] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed May  2 23:34:46 2018
[    16.351] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[    16.351] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    16.352] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[    16.352] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[    16.352] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[    16.352] (**) |   |-->Device "Device0"
[    16.352] (**) |-->Screen "Screen1" (1)
[    16.352] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor1"
[    16.352] (**) |   |-->Device "Device1"
[    16.352] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    16.352] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    16.352] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    16.352] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[    16.352] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    16.352] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    16.352]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    16.352] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    16.352]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    16.352] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    16.352]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    16.352] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    16.352]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    16.352] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    16.352]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    16.352] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[    16.352] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    16.352] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    16.352] (II) Loader magic: 0x5641ee40ce00
[    16.352] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    16.352]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    16.352]    X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
[    16.352]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[    16.352]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[    16.352] (++) using VT number 8

[    16.352] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[    16.353] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    16.358] (--) PCI: (0:0:2:0) 8086:3e92:1849:3e92 rev 0, Mem @ 0xde000000/16777216, 0xb0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64
[    16.358] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 1002:67ff:1462:8a91 rev 207, Mem @ 0xc0000000/268435456, 0xd0000000/2097152, 0xdf000000/262144, I/O @ 0x0000e000/256, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    16.358] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    16.358] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    16.363] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    16.363]    compiled for 1.19.5, module version = 1.0.0
[    16.363]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[    16.363] (II) LoadModule: "amdgpu"
[    16.363] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/amdgpu_drv.so
[    16.367] (II) Module amdgpu: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    16.367]    compiled for 1.19.5, module version = 1.4.0
[    16.367]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    16.367]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    16.367] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[    16.367] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    16.370] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    16.370]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 2.99.917
[    16.370]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    16.370]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    16.370] (II) AMDGPU: Driver for AMD Radeon:
    All GPUs supported by the amdgpu kernel driver
[    16.370] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[    16.370] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics
[    16.370] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics
[    16.370] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics
[    16.495] (II) [KMS] Kernel modesetting enabled.
[    18.514] intel: waited 2020 ms for i915.ko driver to load
[    18.516] (II) AMDGPU(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Screen0" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
```

What else can I do to enable the on-board graphics?

Comment: Do you have the necessary X drivers/kernel drivers installed? What does `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` say when you try to start X with this `xorg.conf`? Any errors?

Comment: I see no errors in /var/log/Xorg.0.log. It appears that intel driver is loaded. But still not available. The on-board graphics works during boot along dedicated card but after system is loaded it is no longer working.

Comment: You cut the log at the interesting part: Any messages from the intel X driver about initializing screens etc. after that? If no, my guess would be there's something wrong with the kernel driver, or a version conflict between X driver and kernel driver.

Comment: I added more log - no thing from Intel driver after that. Is there any way to increase logging level to gain more insight?

Comment: Updating kernek to 4.15 or putting `i915.alpha_support=1` in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT improved the situation. The card is now detected but display is struck on image of dots (Mint load screen)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the setup working so I'm posting it here in case somebody faces similar problem.

First - to get any reaction from the card i needed to set option `i915.alpha_support=1` in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT. After that the on-board card was now working correctly but at least it displayed something, sound through HDMI worked and it was showing up in `Display` utility.

Next I found out that the alpha_support flag is not needed in more recent kernels - so after update to `4.15` I had the same situation but without need for additional boot options.

Then I found some [advice](https://web.archive.org/web/20180417070709/https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/3#TOC-Improve-video-performance-for-Intel-graphics) to get rid of `xserver-xorg-video-intel` driver. After that both graphic cards are working correctly.